# Не получается взять пользователя с БД EF CORE

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework-core

Пытаюсь взять пользователя с БД,

```
var result = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Data).Include(c => c.Role).SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserName == name);
```

но выводит ошибку :

```
"Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.\nObject name: 'ApplicationDbContex'."
```

Но тот же самый код с другого места не вызывает такой ошибки

Вот сам код контекста

```
 public class DbObject
    {
        private static ApplicationDbContex _context;
        public static void Initial(ApplicationDbContex contex)
        {
            _context = contex;

        }
        public static User GetAccountByName(string name)
        {
            Console.WriteLine('h');
            var result = _context.Users.Include(c => c.Data).Include(c => c.Role).SingleOrDefault(s => s.UserName == name);
            return result;
        }
    }
```

А это Startup

```
ApplicationDbContex contex;
            using (var scope = app.ApplicationServices.CreateScope())
            {
                contex = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContex>();
                DbObject.Initial(contex);
                foreach (var item in contex.Users)
                {
                    System.Console.WriteLine(item.UserName);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Код как вы пользуетесь контекстом покажите. Ошибка говорит, что ваш контекст уже уничтожен и через него в базу уже ничего не поедет.

Comment: ну то есть, вы получили контекст из `scope`, после чего вышли из using конструкции, что означает scope умер и всё, что из него получено, тоже умерло, включая контекст, но вы где то в другом коде продолжаете пытаться использовать старый контекст, вот и получаете ошибку.

Comment: Никаких статиков не должно быть.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov выглядит как попытка обмануть систему :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал объект как сервис и всё заработало